# Add column to nstableview in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, nstableview

How to add a new column to an `NSTableView` from the interface builder?

Comment: Am an ignoramous here or is the UI for doing this terrible? Where is right-click "Add Column"? Oh sorry, no right-click on Mac.

Comment: IMO that UX is totally not obvious. And you're not an ignoramus (apart from the spelling issue  )... And it's still just as not-obvious 10 years later!

Answer (score 5):

If you check in the Interface Builder, there are number of **Columns**.

Default is 2, with spinner to add/remove. Simply click on up, you will get one more.

Then you can set it Resizing options as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Just a question: There is already a tag "interface-builder". Do you really think it is good to create another tag "ib"?

Comment: @MartinR: i saw he tagged builder, and few others too. as many of are used to say IB instead of interface builder. and i tried ti set this as synonym, but it says 5 questions required. :(

Comment: "ib" is a very general tag name (it could mean anything in different contexts). The tag has now been removed from the question (which is OK in my opinion). Tags without questions will be deleted automatically after 24 hrs, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags.

Comment: As SO runs by us, if you didn't like that, so probably others will. Its ok. Not an issue. :)

Comment: @MartinR I am the one who removed the tag from the question. I first tried to mark it as synonym, as it is true that *Interface Builder* is known as *IB* amongst Xcode users. Unfortunately, I couldn't – 5 posts requirements - so I just removed it from the question since it was only used by that question, in the hope of seeing it vanish after one day. I believe in full words like `interface-builder` instead of shorts like `IB` that can lead to misinterpretation.

Comment: @Jean: I fully agree, and I think it as been deleted already. - Creating a synonym seems to be a difficult task. I tried it once, but nobody voted for it. Probably nobody reads the synonym suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest. I also posted a request at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164344/make-nsfetchedresultcontroller-a-synonym-for-nsfetchedresultscontrolle, but nothing happened :-)

Comment: @MartinR You got me looking to it ;) And I understand now… The list is endless and there are suggestions such as `master:iphone` <- `synonym:facebook-pictures` cluttering the lot…

Comment: @Jean: Even i tried to link it with Interface Builder. There are dozens of xcodes and ios etc. cant they be merged into one?

Comment: Somebody with sufficient rep must first mark them as duplicate. Then, the magic operates and automatic retagging of the questions occurs. However, this magic requires four conditions to be satisfied: **(1)** The association must get at least *five up votes* from *five different users* that **(2)** have at least *five posts* on the-said tag, **(3)** and went *specifically looking* for the tag on the page described by @MartinR **(4)** and have *enough reputation* to actually cast the vote. Imagine the odds… It happens sometimes of course, but as Martin R said, *it is a difficult task*.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one last question. When I add a new column I do miss a new title for the column. I can add one in the inspector, but is does not show up in the table header view.

Comment: it shows.... you need to scroll. also check if that column size is too small to show the header title